# Should I resize the images at server side or use css for the MVC Application

Tags: css, angularjs, model-view-controller

I develop a MVC + Angular js Ecommerce site with huge number of images been loaded. I have a few queries regarding the performance of the site.

1. There is huge number of images been loaded. Shall I create thumbnails of different size needs and then show them or should i resize with css or any other technique.
2. How can i cache the images for the site.

Comment: [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055611/improving-site-performance-with-many-images) You can go for image compression or lazy loading.

Comment: @Ananya ...Ok will look into

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance and load times, you should create thumbnails server side. Css will only scale the image to your desired width but will still load the bigger one.

I suggest to make your thumbnails and then use those different image sizes for your different needs (smaller ones for product lists, bigger ones for product pages...).

You could even make use of different image src's for the same place toggling them depending on device width so you go even further improving load times on mobile devices. You could achieve this via `ng-src` or even with css with [`srcset`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_source_srcset.asp)